# Advantages of jQuery Widget over regular JS object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, widget

*Edit: Just to be clear, I'm not questioning jQuery's awesomeness.  I use it everywhere.  I just don't understand the advantages of using the Widgets over regular js objects which take advantage of jQuery's functionality.*

I've recently had to use some jQuery Widgets in an app I'm working on, and I'm finding them to be very unintuitive/ugly.  There seem to be a lot of conventions to learn which don't really add any value, and the syntax doesn't accommodate intellisense or easy refactoring.

Don't get me wrong, I use jQuery constantly and I'd hate life without it, just not seeing the value in the widget convention.  I'm sure I'm missing the point because they're so widespread, so please clue me in.  Why do people create jQuery widgets instead of regular js objects?

Oversimplified Example:

Regular Javascript Object:

```
//instantiate & render
var foo = new MyDomain.MyObject('#mySpecialInput', options)
foo.render();

//assign to property
foo.value = 5;
//call method
foo.multiplyBy(2);
//bind event
foo.change(function(){
    alert('it changed');
}
```

Jquery Widget:

```
//instantiate & render
var $foo = $('#mySpecialInput');
$foo.myWidget(options);

//assign to property
$foo.myWidget('option', 'value', 5);
//call method
$foo.myWidget('multiplyBy', 2);
//bind event
$foo.bind('myWidgetChange', function(){
    alert('it changed');
}
```

Comment: one reason will be [jQuery is amazing and does many things :)](http://img180.imageshack.us/img180/3305/addanumbertoanothernumb.png)

Comment: @naveen This is beginning to look more like the real answer :)

Comment: I use the jQuery UI Widget Factory (I think that's what you're referring to) for writing plugins all the time. I don't think I'd ever use them for every object. The Factory allows for calling public methods pretty easily (`$foo.data('myWidget').multiplyBy(2);`).

Answer (score 1):

The biggest thing is that jQuery widgets help bring structure to your app that would be very hard to maintain without them. Of course, they also provide quite a few useful events such as `.bind()`, which can be very useful at times. After a bit of Googling, I found [this article](http://blog.citrusbyte.com/2010/09/16/jquery-widgets-bringing-sanity/) on jQuery widgets which goes into a bit more detail on their advantages.

Personally, I prefer to structure my scripts (more) manually, but if you don't feel like doing that, jQuery widgets can help.

---

Relevant quote detailing how jQuery widgets add structure:

> ...it provides the level of code organization that is very hard to
>   maintain outside of a widget structure.  It changes the code from
>   being imperative (”do this, then that, then another thing, bind to
>   click”) to declarative (”act like an expando thing”).  This frees you
>   up to define what “expando thing” means, while not cluttering or
>   changing the outer layer of your app.  No more multi-hundred line long
>   $(document).ready() blocks.

Comment: This is the argument I see getting thrown around, but how does the jQuery widget bring more structure / ease of maintenance than a regular javascript object?  The article you linked to seems like it makes the assumption that before widgets, we'd all been using global functions and non-OO code?  I understand the need for structure, but  why the unusual syntax?  Why pass property names and methods as strings?  Why re-invent inheritance?  Why not just just use javascript conventions?

Comment: It's a long explanation so I'd recommend you read the article to find out. I'll see if I can find a relevant quote in the mean time.

Comment: The article you linked to seems like it makes the assumption that before widgets, we'd all been using global functions and non-OO code?  I understand the need for structure, but why the unusual syntax?  Why pass property names and methods as strings?  Why re-invent inheritance?  Why not just just use javascript conventions?

Comment: jQuery widgets don't solve the quoted issue at all. The answer for jQuery document ready spaghetti isn't found in jQuery or jQuery plugins.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Thinking Sites' point, Using jQuery widget also offers other OO like features(without investment into building the infrastructure needed to support it in plain js) 

- extensibility
- in place inheritance - allows extending from itself. This allows for modular and highly maintainable code
- concept of public and private methods to improve the readability of the code, and best part is that it maintains chaining since it returns the jQuery object
- Has lot of predefined methods to manage widget's lifecycle : creation, initialization, and destruction

jQuery widget framework can be treated as a tool to mimic OO like functionality.

> It provides a flexible base for building complex, stateful plugins
>   with a consistent API. It is designed not only for plugins that are
>   part of jQuery UI, but for general consumption by developers who want
>   to create object-oriented components without reinventing common
>   infrastructure. --http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138135/Widget%20factory

Comment: I appreciate the well thought-out answer, but almost a year after I asked this question, I feel even more strongly about the goofiness of the widget syntax than I did before.  Using magic strings everywhere is just bad.  There are plenty of other OO frameworks out there now, no reason to use one with weird syntax that doesn't allow for intellisense.

Comment: Yes , to your point the widgets do have weird syntax for simple things as calling a public method on an instance : `$(#selector).widgetName().widgetName("publicMethodName");`

Answer (score 0):

1. Code organization and structuring
2. Namespacing
3. Inheritance
4. Proper scoping and closures
5. Cross-developer readability and common architecture
6. pre-defined properties for access to common items

Comment: I'd argue that all of these are more difficult / unintuitive using jQuery widgets than regular JS objects.  Maybe you can give me an example or two?

Comment: I have a feeling you're looking for someone to confirm your answer rather than getting an honest answer, but I digress.  1 & 5)  If you have your home rolled jquery object, you're impliying a certain structure, which is custom to your application but others may not easily jump into. 3) JS is a scripting language, not strictly OO.  As such, there is no real inheritance.  4) I've had instances where I write a function thinking it's good for a jquery dom object, but it targets the wrong one. 6) You can store the object in a custom data wrapper, but by default widgets store into data.

Comment: Oh, and it's easier to keep jQuery's conventions with a widget, rather than having two different conventions for invoking code.  If it really bothers you that much, I suggest looking into Dojo, which has the syntax you like (though I find it a beast to work with.)

Comment: 1 & 5) The structure I'm implying is basic javascript, nothing "custom" about it.  See the examples I listed in my question.  IMO much more elegant than the widget structure.  "variable.methodName()" certainly is more universal in any language than "variable.typename('methodnName'); 3) I'll defer to experts what constitutes "real" inheritance, but JS inheritance is pretty straightforward and ubiquitous.  4) I don't follow you?  Are you saying widget methods are type-safe?  6) I guess you're saying it's good that widgets are stored in the DOM?  Why store objects in html?

Comment: The jQuery widget convention is different than the jQuery convention.  jQuery: $('#elementID').val();   widget: $('#elementID').widgetName('option', 'value');    I love jQuery, just not the widget syntax